# Plotting of 3D graph in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have to to compare two method named "Main Problem" and "our iteration" by drawing a graph . For this I have the following data .

```
var number      Constraint Number           Iterations  in Main Problem             Iterations in Our Proposal      
1000               100                                 36                                  32   
1000               200                                 40                                    32 
1000               300                                 56                                 35    
1000               400                                 66                                 37    
1000               500                                 70                                   47  


2000               100          76              52  
2000            200         87              57  
2000            300         91              67  
2000            400         95              72  
2000            500         110             83
```

How can I draw a graph from this ?
I want to have a graph like the following .

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to have a line graph with two lines (one for `Main` and one for `Our Proposal`?  Why does it have to be 3D?

Comment: Your data is not clear. Your question is not clear. Where is "our iteration" data? Where is "main problem" data? What does "Constraint number" mean?

Comment: @rishimaharaj , The graph for  " Main" will be based on first 2 column . That is why , I have to 3d graph .

Comment: Thanks for the picture.  What are the three axes & why do they only go to 10?

Comment: The first axis will be for the data of "var number" , The second axis will be for the data of "constraint number" and the third axis will be  for the data of "Main problem"

Comment: And the picture of the graph is random

Answer (score 1):

3d column charts are very bad data visualisation. It is impossible to tell how high a column actually is, since the 3D effect prevents scaling the column against an axis grid.

If you insist on creating a 3D column chart, arrange your data in three columns, then click Insert > Chart > Column > 3D Column.

[image]

Your data sample in your question will need to be re-arranged. Just 3 simple columns, for X, Y and Z.

Comment: I need to compare the "main" method and "our proposal" method based on first two column with their data .

Comment: Please have a look at the edited answer .

Comment: I edited my answer.